# Call to undefined method App\User::givePermissionTo()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using laravel spatie package for role permission, but i have got this error, here is my code

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->givePermissionTo('manager_product_create');
```

Comment: What is the exact problem

Comment: @Vinayak Read the title... That's the error they're getting when using this code.

Comment: This code are included {use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;} and this is function code{use HasRoles;
    public function check(){
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user->givePermissionTo('manager_product_create');
    }}

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to add the trait to the `User` class:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    // ...
}
```

see https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage

Comment: basic usage not detect problem, but direct usage detect problem https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/direct-permissions

Comment: same problem here is code use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class CheckController extends Controller
{
    use HasRoles;
    public function check(){
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user->givePermissionTo('manager_product_create');
    }
}

Comment: The trait contains the methods like `givePermissionTo` so you'll have to add it to your `User` model, not the class (controller) where you're using it.

Comment: if you're planning to just use Permissions: `use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasPermissions;`